# Why is $F^{'}(t) = f(g(h(t)))g^{'}(h(t))h^{'}(t)$ for $F(t) = \int^{h(t)}_{h(c)} f(g(x))g^{'}(x) dx, \ \ t \in J$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Why is $$F^{'}(t) = f(g(h(t)))g^{'}(h(t))h^{'}(t)$$ for $$F(t) = \int^{h(t)}_{h(c)} f(g(x))g^{'}(x) dx, \ \ t \in J$$ ?

This is in a proof of integration by substitution.

$I, J$ are open intervals, $g \in C^1(I)$ with $g(I) \subseteq J$, $h$ satisfies $g(h(y))=y$ for $y \in J$ and $f \in C(J)$.

I'm well aware of the chain-rule of differentiation, but I'm having trouble seeing how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: The [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html) and the [chain rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html).

Make the substitution $u = h(t)$ to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and note that $h(c) \overset{\text{set}}= a = \text{const.}$ Hence, using the chain rule, we find that
$$F'(t) = \frac{dF}{du}\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_a^u f(g(x))g'(x) dx\right)\frac{du}{dx} = f(g(u))g'(u)\frac{du}{dx} = f(g(h(t)))g'(h(t))h'(t).$$